# Offset variable in a Poisson regression measured with error

Tags: poisson-regression, unbiased-estimator, measurement-error, offset

It is known that measurement error in predictors lead to a bias toward zero, and also bias other predictors’ estimates:
[The effect of covariate measurement error on coefficients in regression with dummy variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144335/the-effect-of-covariate-measurement-error-on-coefficients-in-regression-with-dum)
My question is: if I have an exposure variable (so that, in a Poisson regression model, I should insert its log as an offset, i.e., as a regressor with a coefficient restraint to be 1), should I still restraint it to be included as an exposure, or I can leave its estimate to be estimated freely? Of course, my concern is not about the estimate of its coefficient, but about its impact on other variables’ estimates.